# Find last non-empty row (cell) in column and ignore empty cells between values in column

Tags: excel, vba

**Excel Spreadsheet:**

```
        A            B               C             D          E           F 
1
2
3               List_A            List_B
4               Product A    
5               Product B   
6                                 Product A
7               Product C         Product B
8       
9               Product D         Product C
10              Product E   
11                                Product D
12                                Product E
13
14
```

In the above Excel spreadsheet I have list of products in `Column A` and in `Column C`. 
Both lists contain empty cells between the values in the column.

---

Now, I want to identify the **last non-empty row** in both lists: 
In `Column B` this would be `10` 
In `Column C` this would be `12`

---

Therefore, I tried to go with this `VBA`:

```
Sub Identify_last_Row()
Last_Row_Number_Column_B = (Sheet1.Cells(Tabelle3.Range("B3").Row, Sheet1.Range("B3").Column).End(xlDown).Row)
Last_Row_Number_Column_C = (Sheet1.Cells(Tabelle3.Range("C3").Row, Sheet1.Range("C3").Column).End(xlDown).Row)
Sheet1.Range("D1").Value = Last_Row_Number_Column_B
Sheet1.Range("E1").Value = Last_Row_Number_Column_C
End Sub
```

This query goes through but it does not ignore the empty cells between the values in the column.

How do I have to modify the code to identfy the **last non-empty row** and **ignore the empty cells** between the values in the column?

Comment: Maybe try like this : Last_Row_Number_Column_B = Sheet1.Range("B1000000").end(xlup).row

Comment: @karma for your interest `B1000000` is not the last cell of column B (see my answer below) and therefore might fail. Never hardcode the row number if you can determine it by code.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, Thank you for the correction.  I realize that the code will fail if (A) the last row is not "B1000000" and/or (B) the Excel is an older version which has 65536 rows. Thank you once again, PEH.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `xlUp` outgoing from the very last cell in the column:

```
.Cells(.Rows.Count, "B")
```

is the very last cell of column B and `.End(xlUp)` will move upwards until data is found.

```
With Sheet1 'your worksheet
    Last_Row_Number_Column_B = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Last_Row_Number_Column_C = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
End With
```